# mongoDB data redundancy or faster query?

Tags: mongodb, performance, meteor, database-design, collections

I'm working to develop an app with my team. It's based on Meteor and React. We have 2 collections: Rooms and Locations. Each room has an uniq location. We have a page where we list all the rooms and we can filter them. This is the most used feature. Insert of new room or new location can be done only by the admin.

We are design our filter (by date, by floor, by time, by location name). All the property we need are in the Rooms collection, excpetion done for the location name. We come out with two solutions:

1. duplicate the location name used in the filter also for each room in the Rooms collections.
2. get the list of rooms for each property.

I'm try to figure out which one is the best.

1. - first option:
     In that case we only need one collection: Rooms. Will cost O(n). The cost to add the location name to the new room will be the same since we already need to add the property id. The extra cost will be the space on MongoDB to save it.
2. - second option. 
     In this solution we have all the data well structured in the DB. But to filter by location we need to parse each room and find the proper location in the location collections. Only this I think will cost O(n*m).

This is a simple case, we will never scale to much, but since I'm new to mongo I would like to know which one of the two approach can lead to have better performance.

Comment: How big are n and m?

Comment: @MichelFloyd pointed a good question to be made before falling into a possible Premature Optimization

Comment: Btw, i think it's worthy taking a look at Meteor's guide http://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#schema-design

Comment: On the subject of premature optimization ... do it the easy way first. Then only if that fails try something harder. Ditto for learning how to ski.

Comment: @MichelFloyd not so big. But n>m also n+n+n>m.  Meteor guide suggest to use Dernomalization. My opinion have a mapping 1:1 from server to client is the best option. Also filter in the same collection make more sense